# My scanner's nextLine() method isn't working all inputs, how do I fix it?

Tags: java, printing

I'm attempting to write a super simple code where given an integer, the length of that integer (total # of digits) is printed out after being inputted into the console. My code is printing all of the numbers successfully except for the last one. I've encountered this problem frequently and unable to get a solution that works for me.

From a lot of my research so far into people who've answered this question, I've seen that it's typically suggested for a user to add a "nextLine()" statement in order to skip over the /n character at the end of each line, however this has not completely solved the problem for me and I still get a runtime error at the end.

```
    int num = Integer.parseInt(q.next()); // First line of input is # of independent digits that follow, each listed on a line by themselves
    q.nextLine();

    while(num > 0)
    {
        System.out.println(q.next().length());
        q.nextLine();
        num--;
    }
```

I seem to be getting an infinite loop at the end as the program never stops running. The code snippet above with input:
5
200
1
3051

....prints out:
3
1

...while there should be a 4 printed at the end for the number of 3051's digits.

Comment: Perhaps try using `Scanner.hasNextLine() ` in your while condition

Comment: I just tested it using `Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in)` for my input and your code seemed to be working fine.  Maybe the error is elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Well your program works as expected, but it could be simplified and catch bad input.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
final int numberOfIterations = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++) {
    System.out.println(s.next().length());
}
s.close();
```

However this will not fail for a String that isn't even a number, so this case could be catched:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    final int numberOfIterations = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++) {
        final String input = s.next();
        Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println(input.length());
    }
    s.close();
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Bad input!");
}
```

There is also mathemical approach to calculating the number of digits using the modulo-operator.

Comment: "// First line of input is # of independent digits that follow, each listed on a line by themselves" That is completely the intended behavior according to the OP.

Comment: "where given an integer, the length of that integer (total # of digits) is printed out after being inputted into the console." I understand this as compute the number of digits of a given number.

Comment: The first line is the number of integers that follow, the most trivial test case I was given for this (from a set of simple java problems) is actually > 3 > 0 > 10 > 100 which should print out 1, 2, and 3. I attempted using while(true) and am still getting an infinite loop. I'm aware of the modulo operator process but the input for my test cases will always and only be an integer so I thought the method of counting the String length is easier in this situation.